# Create a web deploy package outside visual studio source code

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, msbuild, azure-devops, webdeploy

I'm trying to create web deploy packages through visual studio team services.

Currently, I have created a web deploy publish profile in Visual Studio. I use MSBuild in Visual Studio Team Services to build the solution and create a web deploy package. I then zip the package and save it to a shared location.  However, the issue with this approach is that it does not provide me a way have a same build for different environments. Let us say, I created a web deploy package for DEV environment. Then when I have to deploy the build to SIT environment, I would need to build the solution again and create a package. This way I would have different builds for different environments. I would like to have the same build get promoted to different environment for better traceability and maintenance.

One way I feel I can achieve this is to have a separate build definition for just building the application and save the DLLs to a shared location. I can then have a separate build definition which takes the build from shared location and create a web deploy package from the build. How can I achieve that on VSTS?

Other way possible is creating a label when any deployment happens one environment, say Dev environment. To do the deployment in SIT I can use the source code with same label and then use MSBuild to create a web deployment package. Is there any way to achieve this through VSTS with/ without creating a separate build definition of each environment?

Any other suggestions than above?

Comment: What's the difference between the deployment packages for different environment? Different profile and different web configuration?

Comment: The configuration for each environment is different. The developer may not have access to environment. The SetParameters.xml file in the package would be changed with respect to the environment once the deployment package is created.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VSTS Release Management](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/release-management-vs.aspx) to deploy your deployment package to different environment and use "Tokenizer" task in [Release Management Utility tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks) to update the config file in the package base on the variable for different environment configurations.

And you can also try with [Web Deploy Parameterization](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.sg/2010/07/web-deploy-parameterization-in-action.html).

Comment: I'm already doing web deploy parameterization after creating my package. I did look into VSTS RM option earlier but I saw only Cloud service and Azure Website templates. Now, I noticed "Empty template" option, will have a look. Thanks.